# Inserting Data in WCF REST Service showing Error : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: wcf, rest

I have created the Two Methods one is to **Get** and another one is to **Create**,

For Getting the Data is working fine, but when i trying to post the Data is showing the Error like `Method not Found(404)`

The Code is as following.

Contract Methods :

```
public interface IContactPositionService    {     
   [OperationContract]       
 [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "GET",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetContactPositionList")]    
    List<ContactPosition> GetContactPositionList(); 
[OperationContract]      
  [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddContactPosition")]       
 int AddContactPosition(ContactPosition position);}
```

And Corresponding Serivice class is like :

```
public class ContactPositionService : IContactPositionService
    {
  public List<ContactPosition> GetContactPositionList()
        {
            DataSet ds = clsObj.GetContactPositionsList();
            return ConverterHelper.Convert<ContactPosition>(ds.Tables[0]);
        }

 public int AddContactPosition(ContactPosition position)
        {
          //  throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
```

And in Web.config file i have configured the End Points As :

```
<services>
      <service name="VirtusMobileService.ContactPositionService" behaviorConfiguration="VMS.Position.ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="VMS.Position.EndPointBehaviour"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="VMS.Position.EndPoint"
          contract="VirtusMobileService.IContactPositionService" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VMS.Position.EndPointBehaviour">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VMS.ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="VMS.Position.ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

From the Client Asp.net page we call the Services for adding the Contact person object as like below :

```
private void AddData()
        {
            string sURL = "http://localhost:51293/ContactPositionService.svc/AddContactPosition";       
            ContactPosition order = new ContactPosition
            {
                PositionCode="10550",
                PositionFinbaseId=11,
                PositionTitle="Manager"
            };

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ContactPosition));
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(mem, order);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webClient.UploadData(sURL, "PUT", mem.ToArray());         // Here it is showing Error
             Console.WriteLine("Order placed successfully...");  

}
```

While it comes to , " uploadData " it is showing error like  " 
 remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

```
If i am trying to Get the Data using the   "GetContactPositionList"
```

it showing the data Correctly , but when i am trying to work with
 "PUT" method it is showing that error.

I tested the url in Fiddler , it is showing the same error in Response
 Header "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed"

```
<div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p xmlns="">Method not allowed. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://localhost:51293/ContactPositionService.svc/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
    </div>
```

Please Suggest the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: You get a 405 when method is anything but PUT and a 404 with PUT?  Can you verify for sure that you are getting a 404 and not a 400?

Comment: yest this method error is 405 only

Answer (score 0):

In fiddler you have to specify `application/json` as `Content Type` and it will hit the service  [Try this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386956/RestFul-WCF-JSON-Service-with-client-and-on-Mozill)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "webClient.UploadData", try this..
   webClient.UploadString(sURL, "PUT", data);

Comment: i used both but no use

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably make this much easier on yourself by using [System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx).  It will simplify greatly your interaction with the service, as you will have strongly-typed variables, the method names themselves, and not have to mess with the serialization yourself.

You can replace your `AddData` method as:

```
private void AddData()
{
    // Create the service channel; 'factory' and/or 'svc' can be class members so we can re-use them.
    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IContactPositionService>(new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:51293/ContactPositionService.svc"));
    factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    var svc = factory.CreateChannel();

    ContactPosition order = new ContactPosition
    {
        PositionCode = "10550",
        PositionFinbaseId = 11,
        PositionTitle = "Manager"
    };

    try
    {
        var result = svc.AddContactPosition(order);
        Console.WriteLine("Order# " + result.ToString() + " placed successfully...");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Note:**  This will require your calling project to have a reference to System.ServiceModel.dll and System.ServiceModel.Web.dll.  Additionally, the calling project will need to know about `IContactPositionService` and `ContactPosition`.  I your calling project is not the same as your WCF project, and does not already reference your WCF project, then you can move your service interfaces and objects into a third class library, which you could then share between the WCF host and any consumers.

Comment: Actually we are trying to use benefits of the REST Service , giving the types to client is not a good idea.

Comment: @VGSNaidu You express a fundamental misunderstanding. The types in question really only need to be the structure of request and response to the server, which is already exposed (in fact, necessary) when communicating with the server.